# Can't ping Brother HL-L2390DW on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, ping, brother

I just got a Brother HL=L2390DW Printer/Scanner and installed the drivers on the Brother website.  Here's what I have:

```
# dpkg -l |grep Brother
ii brscan-skey   0.2.4-1   amd64  Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii brscan4   0.4.8-1   amd64  Brother Scanner Driver
ii hll2390dwpdrv:i386 4.0.0-1   i386 Brother HL-L2390DW printer driver (lpd/cups)
ii printer-driver-brlaser 4-1   amd64  printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii printer-driver-ptouch  1.4.2-3   amd64  printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Both the computer and the printer are wirelessly connected to a local network.

I can print fine, but when I ping the IP address of the printer it times out.  Interestingly, when I print out the network report before and after pinging, the printer reports an increase in both "Packets received" and "Packets transmitted", so it seems to be a problem with the printer communicating to my computer.

I tried the [ideas listed here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl1240_all&faqid=faq00002113_000) to fix it:  I tried rebooting both the computer and the printer, and I tried changing the subnet mask on the printer from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0.  But neither of these changed anything.

For context, my ultimate goal is to get the scanner to work.

Comment: Does your wireless router assign IP addresses for both the printer and the computer? Can you control it from there? Does your wireless router broadcast local packets like a hub, or restrict packets to simple. paths?

Comment: To your first question, I think it does.  When I log into the router all devices say "DHCP" as opposed to "Reserved IP".  I'm not sure how to tell the answers to your other questions.

Comment: OK, when I disable my router's firewall I can ping the printer!  However I still can't scan.

Comment: I enabled it again and I can still ping! Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now!

Here's a bunch of things I did. I don't know how many of them were necessary, but I did all of them and now I can scan.

- Copied the contents of `/usr/lib64/sane` to `/usr/lib/sane` because they don't maintain this for Linux and put the files in the wrong place.
- Added:

  ```
  # Brother scanners
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ```

  to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`.
- Installed the "Scanner Setting file".
- For some reason I can't ping `010.000.000.117` (even after the firewall problem was resolved, cf comments to OP), but I can ping `10.0.0.117`. I'm kind of confused because I thought these would be the same.  Maybe I just don't understand IP addresses. Anyway, I changed the IP address in `brsaneconfig4` from `010.000.000.117` to `10.0.0.117`.  Somehow `brsaneconfig4 -q` prompted me to do this, I didn't have to do it manually with `brsaneconfig4 -r` and `brsaneconfig4 -a`.
- Rebooted a bunch of times between different steps.